# How to vary data using SAP and vba?

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

First, I was able to connect SAP GUI to vba. I managed to get a script that works and that sends me an automatic transaction. I would like to know how to make the data entered on SAP for example the date is variable because the date I have to change it every year?

```
   If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
   End If
   If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
   End If
   If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
   End If
    If IsObject(WScript) Then
    WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
     WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
    End If 
   session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TABBL1/
 tabpUCOM1/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TABBL1:RFBILA00:0001/txtBILBJAHR").text = "2015"
```

For example, I would like the "2015" date to be variable, I would like every month I can change this date to put another one without having to start the extraction on SAP GUI again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, you should also indent your code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim MyYear As String

    MyYear = Format(Date, "yyyy")
    If Not IsObject(Application) Then
        Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
        Set Application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
    End If

    If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
        Set Connection = Application.Children(0)
    End If

    If Not IsObject(Session) Then
        Set Session = Connection.Children(0)
    End If

    If IsObject(WScript) Then
        WScript.ConnectObject Session, "on"
        WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
    End If

    Session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSTRIP_TABBL1/tabpUCOM1/ssub%_SUBSCREEN_TABBL1:RFBILA00:0001/txtBILBJAHR").Text = MyYear

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh thank so much, and when I want to make an intuitive interface for my users (I want to put a box with "date?" written on it)?

Comment: `MyYear = Format(InputBox("Insert the date", "Date"), "yyyy")` like this, @user11503878